# Почему не отправляется сообщение в телеграм из-за тега в строке?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет, бот отправляет сообщение в телеграм и все работает, но если добавляю в результирующую строку row[7], то вылазит ошибка post_text error, которая прописана в коде. Единственное, чем отличается эта строка от остальных, внутри нее есть тег переноса строки "br". Ниже сам код. Мне кажется, что просто еще чего-то не хватает(какого-то модуля), так как все закомментированное в коде когда я подставляю - оно отправляет и делает текст жирным в телеграме из-за тега "b". Саму строку в консоли тоже печатает, ошибка только в отправке.

```
import telebot
import config
import random
import requests
import pyodbc 

server = 'ИМЯ СЕРВЕРА'
database = 'ИМЯ БД'
username = 'ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ'
password = 'ПАРОЛЬ'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 1 className, eqpName, partName, nodeName, core, opisanie, FIO, serviceName FROM smsTelegram ORDER BY problemID DESC')


for row in cursor:
   text = row[7]

# '<b>Класс проблемы: </b>'+row[0]+\
#           '\n<b>Оборудование: </b>'+row[1]+\
#           '\n<b>Часть оборудования: </b>'+row[2]+\
#           '\n<b>Узел: </b>'+row[3]+\
#           '\n<b>Суть: </b>'+row[4]+\
#           '\n<b>Детали: </b>'+row[5]+\
#           '\n<b>Служба: </b>'+row[7]+\
#           '\n<b>Специалист: </b>'+row[6]
print(row[7])


def send_telegram(text: str):
    token = "TOKEN"
    url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"
    channel_id = CHAT ID
    url += token
    method = url + "/sendMessage"

    r = requests.post(method, data={
         "chat_id": channel_id,
         "text": text,
         "parse_mode": 'html'
          })

    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("post_text error")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_telegram(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `<br>` добавить `\n`.

Например, перед отправкой:

```
text = text.replace("<br>", "\n").replace("<br/>", "\n")
```

---

Согласно описанию документации https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style доступны только следующие теги:

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough</s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, проблема решена!

Comment: @Homie, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: готово)))))))))

Comment: @Homie, спасибо :)